# Increment value in array php

Tags: php

I am trying to make a function that grabs all the days that have events that are in a database for a certain user. For instance if there were two events on Jan 23, 2013 it would add Jan 23, 2013 to the array. I got it to work so it adds all the days (without adding the same day twice) but now I want to be able to say how many dates are on each day. So on Jan 23, 2013 it would say they have two events in that day.

I hope this makes sense... I have some code for further aid.

PHP Function (grabbing each day that has events)

```
//gets upcoming days that have events for a user
    public function get_upcoming_days_with_events() {
        $return_array = array();
        $date_in=null;
        $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
        $query =$this->db->select()->from('events')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
        foreach ($query->result_array() as $event => $row) {
            $date = strtotime($row['date_due']);
            if (sizeof($return_array) != 0) {
                foreach ($return_array as $date_in_array => $row) {
                    $d = $row['full_date'];
                    if (date('Y-m-d', $date) == $d) {
                        //date is already in array
                        //increment the number of assignments on this day
                        $row['number_of_assignments'] += 1;
                        $date_in = true;
                    } else{
                        $date_in = false;
                    }
                }
            }
            if ($date_in == false) {
                $return_array[] = array(
                    'day' => date('d', $date),
                    'month' => date('m', $date),
                    'full_date' => date('Y-m-d', $date),
                    'number_of_assignments' => 1
                );
            }
        }
        return $return_array;
    }
```

So with this I want to be able to increment $return_array['number_of_assignments'] if my function notices that a certain day has more than one event.

Let me know if you need any more info...

Thanks! :)

Comment: Your `return_array` seems to be empty, How are you passing the values?

Comment: We can save the info in `return_array` by index of `date`, if the date info have not been set into `return_array`, we make an empty info. Each time, we simply increase `number_of_assignments`. Hope my code would be helpful. Any question, feel free to comment here.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We can save the info in `return_array` by index of `date`, if the date info have not been set into `return_array`, we make an empty info. Each time, we simply increase `number_of_assignments`.

```
 public function get_upcoming_days_with_events()
 {
     $return_array = array();
     $user_id = $this->session->userdata('id');
     $query =$this->db->select()->from('events')->where('user_id', $user_id)->get();
     foreach ($query->result_array() as $event => $row)
     {
         $date = strtotime($row['date_due']);
         $date_key = date('Y-m-d', $date);
         if (!isset($return_array[$date_key]))
         {
             $new_item = array(
                 'day' => date('d', $date),
                 'month' => date('m', $date),
                 'full_date' => $date_key,
                 'number_of_assignments' => 0,
             );
             $return_array[$date_key] = $new_item;
         }
         $return_array[$date_key]['number_of_assignments']++;
     }
     $return_array = array_values($return_array);
     return $return_array;
 }
```

Answer (score 1):

Function: [array_count_values()](http://php.net/manual/en/function.array-count-values.php) can help you with this, it gives total number of occurance of a value in an array.

For example:

```
$a = array("apple", "banana", "apple");
var_dump(array_count_values($a));
```

Will output

```
array(
   [apple] => 2,
   [banana] => 1
);
```

So *instead of trying to filter out duplicate events, add them all on the array* and then use `array_count_values()` at last to know their occurenses.